# Python - How do you replace the values of strings stored in a list with the string values from another list?

Tags: python, arrays, string, replace

I have search stack overflow and googled a solution to this problem unfortunately I haven't been able to find a solution.

I would like to replace the values of strings stored in a list with the string values from another list.

For example I have two lists:

```
list_a = ['file_x', 'file_x', 'file_x', 'file_x']
list_b = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

I want the result to return:

```
list_c =['file_1', 'file_2', 'file_3', 'file_4']
```

I am new to python and I am struggling to do this, i have tried using a for loop and str.replace() but I do not know how to match up the key values for each array and replace the 'x' each element of list_a with the string value from the elements of list_b.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to couple corresponding `a`s and `b`s.

```
>>> list(zip(list_a, list_b))
[('file_x', '1'), ('file_x', '2'), ('file_x', '3'), ('file_x', '4')]
```

We can use this *`zip` object* easily in a for loop, unpacking the pairs into separate variables `a` and `b`, then doing the `a.replace('x', b)` and appending the resulting value to our result list:

```
>>> list_c = []
>>> for a, b in zip(list_a, list_b):
...    list_c.append(a.replace('x', b))
...
>>> list_c
['file_1', 'file_2', 'file_3', 'file_4']
```

This can also be written as a short list comprehension:

```
>>> [a.replace('x', b) for a, b in zip(list_a, list_b)]
['file_1', 'file_2', 'file_3', 'file_4']
```

And as Moinuddin points out, using a *format string* here is a better option if you defined the contents of `list_a`

Comment: Thanks! This really helped not only solve the issue but also teach me a new way of processing arrays.

Comment: @Lewis909 they're lists :D

Comment: Ahh thanks because Python doesn't have arrays, it has lists instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you are the one creating the format of `list_a`. Better way will be to use `{}` instead of `x` and format the string using [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format). For example:

```
>>> list_a = ['file_{}', 'file_{}', 'file_{}', 'file_{}']
>>> list_b = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> [a.format(b) for a, b in zip(list_a, list_b)]
['file_1', 'file_2', 'file_3', 'file_4']
```

Comment: I will take a look at str.format(). How is this different to str.replace()?

Comment: `str.replace('x')` will replace all the occurence of `x` even if it was part of string. Where as `{}` will put your value in place of `{}`.

Comment: @Lewis909 notice that your string can also contain literal `{` and `}` (you just need to double them in format string; `'The string can contain {{ and }}, and only this {} here will be substituted'.format(value)`